# Scroll view display

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

[image]How to show only one item at a time in scroll view?

If i use view flipper scrolling will not be possible it will flip but i should get the effect such that user scrolling views lets say in my application i used edit text and one button with in layout this whole layout has to scroll one at a time. 
The reason is only small portion of whole screen has to display this scroll view if multiple items were displayed its not quite enough to differentiate between each layout( Button + edit text)

For Gallery it seems we need to override onFling and shouldn't call super class method but for ScrollView there is no Onfling so which method to override to make one item per view possible

Comment: can you please make the question clear?

Comment: ViewPager will suite for your requirement.

Comment: @DeepakAndroid spacing between items in scroll view

Comment: @DeepakAndroid-lets make the things clear

Comment: @manju-I think you need to use the help of an adapter to customize your views(layouts) and the use a listview,i.e,implement your layout as rows of a listview.

Comment: edited question please check thanks for your effort

Comment: @manju-here is an example of horizontal scroll view with the effects you want.Just with this idea,try to modify it in the way you want http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/